# Find all n such that : $3 \mid (n2^{n}+1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Question :

Determine all natural numbers n such that 3

divides $n\cdot2^{n}+1$

Actually I don't have any ideas to approach but

my efforts :

I see $n=1,2,7,8,13,14$ so I think :

$n=6k+1$ and $n=6k+2$ $k\in \Bbb{N} $

If I'm not wrong but I don't know how ? I prove it ?

Comment: Use $\mod {6}$ then prove

Comment: If you know how to work modulo then $n\cdot 2^n+1=n\cdot(-1)^n+1\pmod{3}$ you want $n(-1)^n+1=0\pmod{3}$ now $n(-1)^n$ is periodic with period at most $6$ so it's enough to look at $n=6k,6k+1,6k+2,6k+3,6k+4,6k+5$ and just reduce it $\mod 3$ to see which ones satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\mod 6$ so that
$$n2^{n}+1 \equiv0 \mod6$$ or $$n2^{n}+1 \equiv3 \mod6$$ 
For the first congruency...
$$n2^n\equiv5\mod6$$
Trying for diffrent $n \mod6$ you find that $n\not\equiv\mod6$

For the second...
$$n2^n\equiv2\mod6$$
Which has solutions at $n\equiv1,2\mod6$

Comment: Thanks can you explain why you chose mod 6 ?

Comment: Your answers were in the form $6k+a$ so i thought it would relate to your calculated results. Sorry if it is confusing though, i realize im the only one to do this.

Comment: Hmm no sorry , we learn @Aops Vol. 2 I will see your method

Answer (score 0):

$$2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 2^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{3} \Rightarrow \\
n2^n+1 \equiv n(-1)^n+1 \pmod{3}$$
Now $3 \mid n2^n+1 \iff 3\mid n(-1)^n+1$, so we will go case by case:

- $n=6k \Rightarrow n(-1)^n+1=6k+1$ has no solutions
- $n=6k+1 \Rightarrow n(-1)^n+1=-6k$ - **all are solutions**
- $n=6k+2 \Rightarrow n(-1)^n+1=6k+3$ - **all are solutions**
- $n=6k+3 \Rightarrow n(-1)^n+1=-6k-2$ has no solutions
- $n=6k+4 \Rightarrow n(-1)^n+1=6k+5$ has no solutions
- $n=6k+5 \Rightarrow n(-1)^n+1=-6k-4$ has no solutions

---

Obvious question is why looking at $n=6k+r$? Well:

- $n=2k+r$ is good for dealing with $(-1)^n$, but doesn't help at all with $3 \mid ...$ part
- $n=3k+r$ helps with $3 \mid ...$, but doesn't say a lot about $(-1)^n$.

Combining both seems a better strategy.

Comment: you beat me to it :). Is it OK if i provide my solution anyway?

Comment: Sure, of course.

Comment: Thanks , but why you decision exactly with $n=6k+r$ ? Can you give me explain

Comment: @EllenEllen it's called intuition. I started with $2k+r$ then $3k+r$ then quickly realised I will need both because of $(-1)^n$ part.

Comment: Thanks sir @rtybase please if you can add something to me add I like your approach!

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis seems very compelling!  All you need to do is to show that $$(n+6)2^{n+6}=64(n+6)2^n\equiv n 2^n\pmod3$$ for all natural $n$. Then your observation that it works for only 1 and 2 out of the first six natural numbers is all you need.

Comment: Was it unnecessary in my answer to put $\mod6$ because everyone else seems to do $\mod3$

Comment: @AopsVol.2 You're trying to show that the number is divisible by 3, so it seems like a natural decision.

Comment: Her answers were in the form $6k+a$ but i see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 0):

$2^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod 3$.

So if $n$ is even then $n2^n + 1\equiv n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $n\equiv -1\pmod 3$.

And so $n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$ so $n\equiv 2\pmod 6$.

And indeed $(6k+2)2^{6k+2}+1=(6k+2)4^{3k+1}+1\equiv (6k+2)*1^{3k+1} +1\equiv 6k + 2+ 1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

If $n$ is odd then $n2^n+1  \equiv -n+1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ so $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

And so $n\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so $n\equiv 1 \pmod 6$.

And indeed $(6k+1)2^{6k+1}+1\equiv 2^{6k+1}+1\equiv 4^{3k}*2 + 1\equiv 1^{3k}*2 + 1 \equiv 2+ 1\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

...

To check that $n\equiv 0,3,4,5\pmod 6$ can not be solutions, clearly $n\equiv 0,3\pmod 6$ imply $3|n$ so $3\not \mid n2^{n} + 1$.

And $(6k + 3 + i)2^{6k+3 + i}+1\equiv i2^{6k+ 3+i}+1\equiv i4^k*2^{3+i}+1\equiv i2^32^i\equiv i8*2^i +1\equiv -i2^i+1\pmod 3$ and $-2^1+1 \equiv -1\pmod 3$ and $-2*2^2+1\equiv -7\equiv -1\pmod 3$.